# Sub menu in option menu identical foreground & background color

Tags: android-menu

I create an option menu with 2 item each is a sub menu.
My problem is that when I press activate one of the sub menu the foreground color is almost identical as the background and I am not able to find out how to change it.
Research on the web seems to indicate there is no easy way to do that which is very surprising to me.
Besides I don't get why by default the colors are the same where in the main menu it is black forground  on white background.

Here is my relevant piece of code:

```
// Create Options Menu
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

// Process clicks on Options Menu items
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.optionmenu_start_new_game:
        createStartNewGameDialog(this,"Start new game","This will reset all scores.");
        return true;
    case R.id.optionmenu_save_playerlist:
        savePlayerListInPreferences();
        return true;
    case R.id.optionmenu_save_game:
        createSaveGameDialog(this,"Save game","Enter game name:");
        return true;
    case R.id.optionmenu_open_game:
        selectSavedGame();
        return true;            
    case R.id.optionmenu_add_player:
        createAddPlayerDialog(this,"New player","Enter name:");
        return true;
    case R.id.optionmenu_remove_all_players:
        createDelAllPlayersDialog(this, "Remove players", 
                "Are you sure you want to suppress all players?" ); 
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

   <item
        android:id="@+id/optionmenu_game_mngt"
        android:title="@string/game_mngt">   
        <menu>
           <item
                android:id="@+id/optionmenu_start_new_game"
                android:title="@string/start_new_game"/>
           <item
                android:id="@+id/optionmenu_save_game"
                android:title="@string/save_game"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/optionmenu_open_game"
                android:title="@string/open_game"/>               
        </menu>        
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/optionmenu_player_mngt"
        android:title="@string/player_mngt">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/optionmenu_add_player"
                android:title="@string/add_player"/>      
            <item
                android:id="@+id/optionmenu_remove_all_players"
                android:title="@string/remove_all_players"/>    
            <item
                android:id="@+id/optionmenu_save_playerlist"
                android:title="@string/save_playerlist"/> 
         </menu>
     </item>            
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same with *Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar*, tried nearly everything with styles. Nothing worked, finally I just used a workaround with Spannable for changing the text color of the sub menu entries.

```
private void makeItemForegroundVisible(MenuItem item) {
  SpannableStringBuilder test = new SpannableStringBuilder(item.getTitle());
  test.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.abc_primary_text_material_light)), 0, item.getTitle().length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

  item.setTitle(test);
}
```

That does the trick, but it's clearly not the best way to do it I'm sure.

Comment: Thx
It seems to be device depedent cause when I test on an emulated Nexus (instead of my own galaxy s2 device) there is no such problem.
I think I will replace my textfield by some image to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had another problem with the appcompat light dark action bar theme and surprisingly the solution for that problem also fixed the sub menu problem on the affected device:

**style.xml**

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when using Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar but worked around it by overriding actionBarWidgetTheme in my theme definition:

```
<style name="AppThemeDay" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light</item>
</style>
```

It seems that Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar has this problem but that Theme.AppCompat.Light displays menu items similarly but does not exhibit the problem.